# Google Scripts external spreadsheet data validation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, validation

I was interested in automating data validation of a Google Spreadsheet against another Google Spreadsheet using Google Scripts. I can't seem to find a way to reference the range of another spreadsheet using the `openById` method. Any thoughts?

```js
function externalSheetDataValidation() {
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    //var dataValidationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("dataValidationRules");
    //var dataValidationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Z2s1bSRIhZzBBrMfPmhEphnPx-kJdV3LLlbv0L59g8/edit#gid=0");
    var dataValidationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("10Z2s1bSRIhZzBBrMfPmhEphnPx-kJdV3LLlbv0L59g8");
    var sheet = dataValidationSheet.getSheets()[0];
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A3:A4");
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
        .requireValueInRange(range, true)
        .setAllowInvalid(false)
        .build();
    cell.setDataValidation(rule);  
    Logger.log(dataValidationSheet.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, the issue you are having is selecting a data range from an external spreadsheet?
Im assuming dataValidationSheet is supposed to be the external sheet.  It looks like you were on the right track.  It looks like the issue is that you are expecting the sheet to be active once you grab it.
Try this change:
`var range  = sheet.getRange("A3:A4");`
Currently you are grabbing the external sheet, but then getting the range from the sheet that was already active.  Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for you help!  Yes, you are correct, dataValidationSheet is the external sheet. I tried deleting the .getActiveSheet() method from the range definition and the code runs but, it is still referencing the active sheet and not the external sheet values for data validation.

Comment: I totally missed the big picture when I answered this morning, I hadn't had my first cup of coffee yet.  As far as I know there is no way to set an external range as a data validation rule.  You might be able to figure out a work around, depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  For example, if you wan't to reference a range whose data won't be changing, you could grab the values and make a VALUE_IN_LIST type rule.  If it is an add-on, you could possibly have this list repopulate every time the addon is opened,  but as far as I know, unfortunately, there is no easy way to do it.